# Get URL-prefix like matching, using RegEx in Stylish?

Tags: regex, stylish

I am coding custom CSS for Facebook using *Stylish*.
Everything goes well except that I need to have some custom values under the condition of URL-suffix. The only thing that comes close is URL-prefix which is the exact opposite.

So I was wondering if I could do something like:

Detect if URL is like either:
`www.facebook.com/*/posts`  or just  `*/post`

where * could be any value.
Is it possible to do this through RegEx?
I googled it but I couldn't make anything out of it.

I want to apply some CSS code only when viewing some individual Facebook posts, and the URLbar shows:

```
www.facebook.com/User/Posts/PostID.php
```

Therefore, I would only like to detect if Post or post/postID.php exists and apply the style.

Comment: unclear . Explain a bit of what did you want to match and what did you won't.

Comment: www.facebook.com/*/posts
For example:
www.facebook.com/aires/posts SHOULD MATCH
www.facebook.com/posts/aires SHOULD NOT MATCH

Comment: post the above comment in your question and what won't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below regex would match the links which contain the string `/posts`,

```
(?=.*?\/posts).*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tA0sV0/2)

Comment: So this will detect /post anywhere in the url?

Comment: Thanks a lot, fast answer aswell.
It was not exactly what I expected but this will do as-well :)